# Why does using M1 Macbook air in closed-clamshell mode slow down the WIFI significantly?

Tags: display, wifi, closed-clamshell

I am using M1 Macbook Air and when I connect it to an external display connected over HDMI cable, the wifi speed slows down tremendously. I don't know how these two are related to each other, but I've tested it multiple times and using it in closed clamshell mode definitely affects the wifi speed.

This is my Macbook book in its regular state:
[image: Regular state]
And this is my Macbook in closed clamshell:
[image: Closed clamshell state]

As you can see it won't even connect to the test server for the speed test..... Super frustrating.

Comment: Can you add some measurements of WiFI speed when open or closed?

Comment: So Wi-Fi slows down when connected to the external display, and slows down even more when in clamshell mode?

Comment: Metal can block Wifi signals, so perhaps it is blocked by your screen.