# Wifi Drops when in Clamshell Mode

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, closed-clamshell

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) in clamshell mode, connected to a 4k monitor and power through a USB-C hub. If I use only the external screen, with the lid closed, wifi becomes unusable. As soon as I open the lid (both screens on, mirrored) the problem goes away.

In closed-clamshell mode:

```
moe@Moes-MBP ~> ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.217.110): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=254.020 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=206.079 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=1207.436 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=214.452 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=224.992 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=6 ttl=117 time=230.388 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 25.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 206.079/389.561/1207.436/366.069 ms
```

Immediately after opening the lid:

```
moe@Moes-MBP ~> ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.217.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=117 time=17.263 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=17.297 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=44.884 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=13.996 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=19.013 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=22.815 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 13.996/22.545/44.884/10.329 ms
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: This user seems to have the same problem: [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/414735/353698)

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, buying a wifi router with 5GHz support (not just 2.4Ghz) solved this problem for me.